# Django Class Based View - How to access POST data outside of post() method

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a CBV based on a TemplateView
It has a **post(self)** method to access user input.
Also, it has a **template_name** property which should be populated with data from **post()**.
No Django models or forms are used here.

Attempt to extract data within post method:

```
# views.py
class ReturnCustomTemplateView(TemplateView):

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        chosen_tmplt_nm = self.request.POST.get('tmplt_name')
        print(chosen_tmplt_nm)  # correct value.
        # how do I use it outside this method? (like bellow)    

    template_name = chosen_tmplt_nm
```

... or is there any other way I can get the data from request.POST without def post()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [**`get_template_names()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names) which returns an iterable (for example a list) of template names to search for when determining the name of the template, so:

```
class ReturnCustomTemplateView(TemplateView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [self.request.POST.get('tmplt_name')]

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
```

I would however advise to be *careful* with this: a POST request could be *forged*, so a hacker could make a POST request with a different template name, and thus try to obtain for example the content of the `settings.py` file or another file that contains sensitive data.

Comment: Django sends 405: Method Not Allowed (POST) 

(I have the csrf token in the form)

Comment: @AntonFrolov: that is because a `TemplateView` by default does *not* handle a POST request.

Comment: @AntonFrolov: you can let it handle it by calling `self.get(*args, **kwargs)`. See edit.